# Checkbox in form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, view, helper

Sorry for stupid question but I dont understand how to use check_box helper in rails. I read the documentation, but did not understand how create ckeckbox in `form` for `user[:role]` with params `customer` and `provider`(and maybe `admin`)

Comment: can you include the html form you're expecting? we can convert it to use the rails helpers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The brief of check_box helper see: [check_box_tag](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-check_box_tag)

Answer (score 1):

first read and understand the brief Ganesh pointed out. If user can have only one role, you need radio buttons or select list. For multiple roles, you need a Role model and check boxes.

Answer (score 1):

There is an example. It should works for scaffolded User model with :role atribute.

```
<% for role in %w(customer provider admin) %>
  <p>
    <%= check_box_tag "role", role, (params[:role] && params[:role].include?(role)) %>
    <%=h role %>
  </p>
<% end %>
```